# find all occurrences of required and included in a php file

Tags: php, regex

I understand `preg_match_all` can get me this information. I need

```
include("xxxx");
include_once("xxxx");
require("xxxx");
require_once("xxxx");
```

and any other permutations allowed by PHP that I may not know of.

Not having much luck building the expression.

Comment: it's actually `require("xxxx");` and `require_once("xxxx");` not required

Comment: I did not understand what the result must be but if you need to get xxxx in the result you can use:
`preg_match_all('/(include|include_once|require|require_once)\("([^"]*")\)/', $source_text, $result);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
(include|require)(_once)?[( ]["'].+["']\)?;
```

But I wouldn't rely on RegEx to do this kind of job.

Comment: You should also consider single quotes. so ["'] instead "